# Insert Carriage return every 2 words using regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, insert, return

I'd like to make a regex that inserts a carriage return every 2 words...
Also the string to format is in an array(does that make any difference?)
the problem is : I heard about regex 2 weeks ago and so far it makes me feel like someone is litterally stepping on my brain. 
So for the moment I came up with that (bear with me...)

```
ticketName[i] = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing';
ticketName[i] = ticketName[i].replace(/(?:[a-zA-Z])* {2}/ig, ',');
```

Surprisingly...it doesn't work !

Can anyone help me?

Also when I'm done with this, I will need to make another one replacing the end of the sentence by '...' when the sentence exceeds a certain number of characters. if you have any insights on that since I'll probably be back for that one also...
Searched the site, only found replacing end of sentences with carriage returns. and I'm guessing my pb lies in the defining of the word.
Thanks a bunch

Comment: ` {2}` matches 2 spaces.

Comment: Where is the carriage return in your regex?

Comment: @silentboy, well,while testing I was using a coma cause I'm not 100% sure of how to do a carriage return... I think it's \r or \n...but while testing prefered not taking a chance

Comment: a comma is used to separate function arguments too. So you actually give 3 argument to the replace function. And to give comma  as argument you have to escape it with a slash.

Comment: Thanks a lot every one !!! For the answers and the detailed explanations on how regex work. Awesome community! For the moment none has worked right away, but I think I'm probably doing something wrong. I'll continue my testing over the weekend. and get back to the forum on monday :)

Comment: Would you tell us what result you are getting? Show us what "none has worked right away" means for you? Many of these answers were tested by the respective authors, and worked for them... My (tested) example is at http://jsfiddle.net/zSeNG/1/

Comment: Ok, so I tested and just as I thought: many of them worked, but I was doing it wrong...I forgot my variable was an innerHTML and I just had to change the \n by <br />...I know right... Thanks again everyone for the answers and also the link to the tutorial. Floris I used regex ;) it works great!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm too new on this site to be allowed to vote, so I have no other choice than send my votes as nothing more than a mental vibe...gnnnn

Comment: You need 15 reputation to vote... And you now appear to have it. You are no longer "too new"!  Glad we were able to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoilt for choice, you are. I just thought I would add one more option, and answer your second question at the same time:

```
var mytest = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing";
var newtext = mytest.replace(/(\w+\W+\w+)\W+/ig,"$1\n");
alert(newtext);

result:
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amet consectetur
adipisicing
```

Note - the last word ('adipisicing') was not matched, so not replaced. It's just there at the end (and without a trailing `\n`).

*Explanation:*

Regexp:

```
(     start a capture group comprising:
\w+   one or more "word" characters
\W+   one or more "not a word" characters
\w+   one or more "word" characters
)     end capture group
\W    followed by non-word
/ig   case insensitive, global (repeat as often as possible)
```

and replace with:

```
$1    "The thing in the first capture group (everything matched in parentheses)
\n    followed by a newline
```

**second question:**

By the way - since you were asking about the "other" problem - how to terminate a sentence in `...` after a certain number of words, you could do the following:

```
var abbrev = mytest.replace(/((\w+\W+){5}).*$/,"$1...");
alert(abbrev);

result:
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
```

Explanation:

```
(    start capture group
(    start second group (to be used for counting)
\w+  one or more "word" characters
\W+  one or more "non word" characters
){5} match exactly five of these
)    end of capture group
.*$  followed by any number of characters up to the end of the string
```

and replace with

```
$1   the contents of the capture group (the first five words)
...  followed by three dots
```

There - two answers for one question!

If you want to do both, then do the "abbreviate a long sentence" first, then cut it into shorter segments. It's a bit harder to count words across multiple lines with regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
str.replace(/((\s*\w+\s+){2})/g, "$1\n");
```

Eg:

```
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing';
str.replace(/((\s*\w+\s+){2})/ig, "$1\n");
"Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit 
amet consectetur 
adipisicing"
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
(         -> start of capture group. We want to capture the two words that we match on
(         -> start of an inner capture group. This is just so that we can consider a "word" as one unit.
\s*\w+\s+ -> I'm consider a "word" as something that starts with zero or more spaces, contains one or more "word" characters and ends with one or more spaces.
)         -> end of capture group that defines a "word" unit.
{2}       -> we want two words
)         -> end of capture group for entire match.
```

In the replace, we have `$1\n` which simply says "use the first capture group and append a newline".

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUsXY/).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find one of the regex solutions posted here works for you.

Alternatively, the same can be accomplished using the string split() and substring() methods. The below code does this and a fiddle's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VCTLB/1/). This is not nearly as elegant as using regex though.

Example Source Code

```
ticketName = new Array();
ticketName[0] = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing';
tmparray = new Array();
tmparray = ticketName[0].split(" ");



finalName = ""; // hold final name
totallength=0;
maxlength = 30;

// add a carriage return (windows) every two words
for (var i=0; i<tmparray.length; i++){
    finalName += tmparray[i]+" ";
    if ((i>0) && (((i-1)%2) == 0))
        finalName +="\r\n";
}

// truncate result if exceed final length and add .... where truncated
if (finalName.length>maxlength)
    finalName= finalName.substring(0,maxlength)+ ".....";

alert(finalName);
```

Comment: well, on this one I'd rather use a regex. but thanks though cause i didn't know that this was possible in js. it will probably come in handy on some other use.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by what's wrong in your regex:
- `[a-zA-Z]` you don't need to specify `A-Z` as you're using the *i* modifier
- `{2}` as stated by Matt Ball in the comments, you're only trying to match 2 consecutive whitespaces here, you'd need to use parenthesis to repeat the whole group instead
- `','` you said you wanted to replace by carriage return (\r), but you're inserting a comma

Now, the best way to match a word (in my opinion) is the following:

```
/\b[a-z]+\b/
```

([Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for the \b, and we'll use [lazy operators](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html))
You could do that:

```
replace(/(\b[a-z]+\b.*?\b[a-z]+\b)/, '$1\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing'
  .match(/([a-z]+\s){2,2}/gi)
  .join('\n');
```